# How to convert a Delphi application into a web application?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

We have a POS Software developed with Delphi 7 and we like to know how to convert this Delphi application into a web application. We did a lot of research but most of the information is from years ago. Maybe there is something new (2012).

Comment: You mean Delphi desktop application?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot convert a desktop Delphi application to a web application.  You will have to rewrite it.  You can write a web application using Delphi, but the controls and strategy you will use are quite different from a desktop application.  If you choose Delphi as your web development environment you will be able to reuse any non-visual code.  Using Delphi to develop web applications is not very common.

Comment: This anwer was true back in 2012, but nowadays there are some options to convert a desktop Delphi application to a web application, like Thinfinity VirtualUI.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can!
http://www.athtek.com/web-application-kit.html

"It can easily transfer your C/S type software to browser side to be an internet application effectively"

Online demos:
http://www.athtek.com/web-application-kit/demos.html